# Using the middle mouse button to switch between workspaces in Gnome

Tags: gnome, xfce, gnome-panel

In XFCE when I put the mouse over the workspace switcher in the taskbar and roll the middle mouse button, it switches the workspaces.

When I do this in a Gnome session, nothing happens.

So now what?

Answer (score 1):

Mouse scroll workspace switch is Xfce4 feature. User can enable or disable switching by placing mouse over Workspace Switcher, right click-Properties. Feature can be very annoying if you do few things at a time in different workspaces. If I remember correctly, Gnome2 has same option.

[Gnome library](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/user-guide.html#gosoverview-41)